# No puedo relacionar dos tablas en mi base de datos

Tags: mysql, sql

el problema es el siguiente.
Tengo más de una tabla en mi bd, y en la tabla principar pongo en una casilla el "id" correspondiente al dato que contiene la otra tabla secundaria, y no sé escribir un código que me permita en vez de ver el "id" ver el dato. Les dejo imágenes por si no me expresé bien y el código con el que intenté relacionar las tablas.

[image: tablas]

```
$sql  = "SELECT p.id,p.descri,.p.precio,m.nombre,c.nombre,p.pais,p.imagen ";
$sql .="FROM productos AS p";
$sql .= "JOIN marcas AS m ";
$sql .= "JOIN categorias AS c ";
$sql .= "ON p.marca=m.id ";
$sql .= "ON p.catego=c.id ";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

  $id     = $reg["id"];
  $descri = utf8_encode($reg["descri"]);
  $precio = $reg["precio"];
  $marca  = utf8_encode($reg["marca"]);
  $catego = utf8_encode($reg["catego"]);
  $pais   = utf8_encode($reg["pais"]);
  $imagen = $reg["imagen"];
```

Con este otro código si me funciona, pero no es lo que busco

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM productos";
  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

  while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

    $id     = $reg["id"];
    $descri = utf8_encode($reg["descri"]);
    $precio = $reg["precio"];
    $marca  = utf8_encode($reg["nombre"]);
    $catego = utf8_encode($reg["nombre"]);
    $pais   = utf8_encode($reg["pais"]);
    $imagen = $reg["imagen"];
```

Este es el código de las tablas

Productos:

```
CREATE TABLE `productos` (
    `id` INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `descri` VARCHAR(316) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `precio` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `marca` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `catego` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `pais` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `imagen` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_spanish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
```

Marcas

```
CREATE TABLE `marcas` (
    `id` INT(3) NOT NULL,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_spanish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

y categorías

```
CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
    `id` INT(2) NOT NULL,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_spanish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Desde ya gracias, esto es para una prueba importante que tengo en clase.

Comment: Coloca por favor como texto la estructura (columnas) de tus 3 tablas involucradas por favor

Comment: Buenas, acabo de editar la pregunta, supongo yo que te servirá lo agregado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno el primer punto que yo corregiría es que:

- No tienes llaves foráneas declaradas en la tabla `productos` que haga relación tanto para la tabla `categorías` como para la tabla `marcas`
- Antes de proceder **aegurate de respaldar tu información**
- Las llaves primarias y foráneas deben del mismo tipo, entonces no puedes utilizar una columna de tipo `VARCHAR` para vincular una que sea de tipo `INT`
- Las llaves primarias que son declaradas de tipo `AUTO_INCREMENT` y `PRIMARY KEY` no necesitan los atributos de `NOT NULL` y `UNSIGNED` pues no permitirán valores negativos ni tampoco nulos
- Tu tabla productos debe tener 2 `CONSTRAINT` a los cuales:

  - Les asignaremos un nombre para diferenciarlos
  - Les daremos una relación de llave foránea que apunta a llave primaria

Tu código debería quedar así:

```
CREATE TABLE `marcas` (
    `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci'
) COLLATE='utf8_spanish_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
    `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci'
) COLLATE='utf8_spanish_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `productos` (
    `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `descri` VARCHAR(316) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `precio` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `pais` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `imagen` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `marca_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `categoria_id` INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_productos_marcas FOREIGN KEY(marca_id) REFERENCES marcas(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_productos_categorias FOREIGN KEY(categoria_id) REFERENCES categorias(id)
)
COLLATE='utf8_spanish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
```

**La consulta**

Prueba con esta consulta

```
SELECT  productos.id,
        productos.descri,
        productos.precio,
        marcas.nombre,
        categorias.nombre,
        productos.pais,
        productos.imagen
FROM marcas 
JOIN productos ON marcas.id = productos.marca_id
JOIN categorias ON categorias.id = productos.categoria_id;
```

Comment: Te agradezco mucho, pero corregí todos los errores de la tabla, y aún así la consulta sigue sin funcionarme :/

Comment: Que error te sale? Ya deberías obtener los valores deseados @Andres90tl

Comment: Voy a probar una última cosa y ya te digo
reitero, gracias por tu paciencia

Comment: No hay caso, en la tabla sí que me salen los valores, pero cuando hago la consulta.
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\24\1.paginas\productos.php on line 50

`````````````````
while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
`````````````````

El error siempre sale en esa línea, significa que la consulta falla

Comment: No el error no es por la consulta, el error está a nivel de sintaxis de tu PHP, déjame ver

Comment: Dos comentarios primero en p.precio tienes un punto justo antes quitalo, por otro lado no descompongan la consulta en múltiples renglones déjala en uno solo y mete la consulta completa solo en un par de comillas @Andres90tl

Comment: Ahora sí, me ayudaste un montón, muchas gracias por todo!!!